# How to hide Stencil in Texture Paint Mode

Tags: interface, shortcut, texture-painting, 3d-view

Is there any way to hide the stencil overlay in the texture paint mode of blender?
It kind of gets irritating when trying to view whats been painted on the view?
Of course I can do it from the tool panel, but are there any shortcuts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't make the stencil disappear using any shortcuts. What you can do is grab it (hold <kbd>RMB</kbd> and drag the mouse from left to right), then place it on a right/left side of a screen. You may see only a small fragment of it. Then you can grab it again and place back on the previous position.

[image]